# Django-ajax multiple requests.

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working with django-ajax module and I have some ajax based work:

**views.py**

```
@ajax
@login_required
def search_dist(request):
    dist_list = Distributor.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        starts_with = request.GET['query']

    if starts_with:
        dist_list = Distributor.objects.filter(
            surname__istartswith=starts_with)
    return render(request, 'distributors/distributors_list.html', {'distributors': dist_list})
```

**JS**

```
var search = $('#search');
search.on('keyup', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var query;
        query = search.val();
        ajaxGet('{% url "distributors:search_dist" %}', {
            'query': query
        }, function(content) {
            $('#distributors').html(content);
            set_favorite();
        })
    }, 1000);
});
```

It works just fine, but when I open my console I see that server makes too many requests for the same thing. For example: after I input 'Jhon' I see
`[03/Jun/2015 10:56:36]"GET /distributors/search_dist?query= HTTP/1.1" 200`
25 times. Is something wrong with my code or it's just normal?

Comment: Can you use `blur` instead of `keyup`?

Comment: @Tushar, it makes less requests but I have to defocus form to submit query and this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've only used `setTimeout`. But you'll need to use `clearTimeout` function, too.

```
search.on('keyup', function() {
    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var query = search.val();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        ajaxGet('{% url "distributors:search_dist" %}', {
            'query': query
        }, function(content) {
            $('#distributors').html(content);
            set_favorite();
        })
    }, 1000);
});
```